# Prove that $\exp(x)=3x$ has at least one solution for $x\in [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove that $\exp(x)=3x$ has at least one solution $x \in [0,1]$.

$$e^x=3x$$

$$\Leftrightarrow e^x-3x=0$$

Let $$f(x) = e^x - 3x$$
$$f(0)=e^0 - 3 \cdot 0 = 1 > 0$$
$$f(1)= e^1-3 \cdot 1 = e - 3 < 0$$
Thus, since $f(1) < 0 < f(0) $, by the IVT: 
$$\exists \zeta \in [0,1]\text{ such that }f(\zeta)=0 \Leftrightarrow e^\zeta = 3\zeta$$
$\Box$

Is that correct? Is there something I can improve?

Comment: You could improve the exposition by using more words and writing out quantifiers like $\exists$. But the proof is correct, except for an easily fixable mistake on the last line.

Comment: Last line should be $e^\zeta = 3\zeta$, not $f(\zeta) = \zeta$. Otherwise good.

Comment: Perhaps shorter: *because $\exp(0)=1 \gt 3\cdot0 $ and $\exp(1)\approx 2.71 \lt 3\cdot 1 $ and the exponential-function is continuous in the interval $0 ... 1$ for x, there must be one point of equality*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well done. Don't be afraid, though, to use *words*: E.g. Why not *write out* "...Then there exists a $\zeta$..."

Final sentence: ***say*** (write) $\quad e^\zeta = 3\zeta,\;$ and not $\;f(\zeta) = \zeta$.

And...write out "Intermediate Value Theorem", instead of IVT. Certainly, it is fine to abbreviate when you are simply proving something in your own notes. But if you are attempting to communicate to *another* (e.g., homework, presentation, etc), unless you have previously made explicit what IVT means, "write it out."

Acronyms are handy for saving time while taking notes or writing on a blackboard, but if you are using them to present solutions, write out the theorem's "name" and if you must, follow with a parenthetical acronym if you need to refer to it often:  E.g. "By the Intermediate Value Theorem (IVT), we know ... "

Comment: +1 for "*words*." I'm inconsistent about things like the double arrows myself, but I strongly feel quantifiers like $\exists$ are for blackboard shorthand only and should be written out in contexts like this.

Comment: thanks, Potato. Yes, for some reason, students sometimes think "the more symbols, the better." Not usually true.

Comment: OK I have corrected it.For me, it seems more clearly represented when I use quantifiers, but of course if most people see it in an other way, I should use perhaps more words...

Comment: Nice work. Indeed, your proof **is correct**. My suggestion that you don't shy away from using "words" is simply a  recommendation. If it's for yourself, your own notes, e.g., and you prefer being concise, by all means, be concise. But just know that mathematicians don't necessarily take "where ever possible, use symbols" to be "better math."

Comment: Sometimes it is also easier or faster to write quantifiers than to look up the right sentence in a foreign language, but I think it is also  a matter of habit.

Comment: I can fully understand the preference for "universal language of math" over writing in a tongue other than you're native tongue! Perhaps, after doing your work with symbols that are more comfortable and quicker for you, reserve time, each week, *at a later date*, to practice "filling out" proofs or notes with words. The "English" used in proofs is already limited in scope: there are certain repetitive phrases you'll want to get down ("For all", "there exists," "if and only if", "therefore," etc). That said, nice work.

Comment: @amWhy: nice discourse/feedback +1

Comment: @Babak I love the flower! it really does look like a flower, too ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Also $f$ can have at $most$ one root between $0$ and $1$
 because, if $f(x) = e^x-3x$,
$f'(x) = e^x-3$,
so that $f'(x) < 0$ for $0 \le x \le 1$
(since $1 \le e^x \le e < 3$).